# Reading event counters with concurrent exection

Tags: cuda, profiling, nvidia

I am trying to read performance counters with nvprof while executing two kernels concurrently.

```
nvprof --concurrent-kernels on --events fb_subp0_write_sectors ./myprogram
```

However by doing this the kernel execution seems to serialize. What I want out of this is exactly how they perform when they are running concurrently.

Is it possible at all to read performance counters when kernels are running concurrently? I do not necessarily need performance per kernel, aggregate data is perfectly fine.

I am running on a Kepler gpu with compute 3.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. nvprof v7.5 and earlier does not support collection of performance counters in a way that is useful for investigating the performance of concurrent kernels. I recommend you submit a feature request through the NVIDIA developer program. This is on the teams task list. Customer feedback helps move features up on the list.

Comment: This is what I was guessing. How about cupti?

Comment: CUPTI has a mode that will allow you to read the counter values from the CPU. The frequency at which you can read the events is rather low and the values will not be bound to the time range around the concurrent kernels.